# pyinstaller: command not found

Tags: pyinstaller

I am trying to install `pyinstaller` on `ubuntu 18.04`. After installation using

> `pip install pyinstaller`

when i run

> `pyinstaller myscript.py`

i get the error

> `pyinstaller:command not found`

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798660/pyinstaller-command-not-found) answer but didn't understand it. A step by step clarification would be great.

Comment: The first answer in your linked thread should work (this is the recommended way to run modules installed with pip). Maybe it does not work for you, because pip is the pip from Python 2 and your python is Python 3. Please add the output of the commands `pip --version` and `python --version` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was -

[image]

Running the script: (inside your project folder, open terminal then do -)

> pyinstaller --specpath ./dist --distpath ./dist --workpath ./dist --onefile ./src/run.py

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use another file to install it, you can do this:

```
name@machine-name:$~ python3 -m PyInstaller myfile.py
```